# Leaflet Popup not registering click events

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to embed an interactive image carousel within a Leaflet popup but any content I place within the popup element does not register mouse events.

I created a simple test to see if I could register a simple click event onto a popup, but nothing happens. Leaflet markers register click events fine, but on popups its disabled.

Why is this happening and how do I enable popup to register mouse events?

[JsFiddle Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/3xat1vj8/1/)

```
// create a map in the "map" div, set the view to a given place and zoom
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

// add an OpenStreetMap tile layer
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

// add a marker in the given location, attach some popup content to it and open the popup
var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
var popup = L.popup()
    .setContent('<p>Hello world!<br />This is a nice popup.</p>')
        .openOn(marker)
 marker.bindPopup(popup); 
 //marker registers click events
 marker.on("click", displayMarkerMessage);
 // popup does not register click events
 popup.on("click", displayPopupMessage);

 function displayMarkerMessage(){
 console.log("marker click");
 } 

 function displayPopupMessage(){
 console.log("popup click");
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a click event on the DOM element when you open the popup.

```
 function displayMarkerMessage(){
   var popup  = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-popup-content-wrapper');
   if(popup != null && popup.length > 0){
     L.DomEvent.off(popup[0]); //to reset all events on the popoup, maybe else it is called twice
     L.DomEvent.on(popup[0],'click',displayPopupMessage);
   }
 }
```

if you have multiple popups open at the same time, you have to loop through the popups and add the click events to them.

Also you can use the `popupopen` event to get the popup container and add the click event. https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#popup-popupopen

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer, this solved my problem and my popup image carousel is now working finally.